# Download mails from backup server to exchange

Tags: email, backup, exchange, email-server, exchange-2016

I have a problem in our company. We are using Exchange 2016 and a backup mail server from a different provider, as we were using this provider before we came up with our own server. We had a problem last week, when the server fell down, all the emails went to the old, backup server which is okay. But my question is: Is there any automatic way to let Exchange download to Exchange mailboxes all the emails that fell to old mailboxes during the drop-out of our server? We are hugely addicted to our emails and we don't want to let some emails be missing. Sorry for my english, thanks for help.

Comment: There's no native way to do this in Exchange 2016 that I'm aware of but there are third party utilities that reportedly have the ability to do this.

Comment: Hint for the future, don't use backup mail servers, unless you are 1000‰ certain that you know exactly all the caveats and consequences this might have.

Comment: http://www.msexchange.org/software/POP3-Downloaders/

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way in Exchange to do that. But as an idea (if your solution you build isn´t an "Backup MX" as mentioned [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_backup_mx)) you could use [imapsync](https://imapsync.lamiral.info/) to download emails from the 2nd IMAP postbox and store it inside the Exchange mailbox from the users on your side. However the issue with the password might be something tricky and you might wish to implement something like written on the Microsoft website [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/949926) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8c8b4605-efae-49eb-a118-54aa418de6c2/access-shared-mailbox-via-imap-on-exchange-2010?forum=exchangesvrgenerallegacy) and set up an delegation account.

Answer (score 1):

POP3 Connector was introduced and removed in 2003 SBS, you could use any 3rd party software or configure pop3 on each outlook instance to download email from the external/backup server to your exchange server.

One of the better 3rd party utils: 
https://www.mapilab.com/exchange/exchange_pop3/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of Backup & Recovery solution which will enable you to Backup your Exchange information store, to get in detailed check this [link](http://www.msexchange.org/software/Backup-Recovery/).

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to all of you, all your help give me new look to this problem in the end we are not going to buy any pop3 connector, we just agreed with our provider of our old server to configure that server as a backup and it should be okay than. But again, thanks a lot for your time and patience